# Android Bitmap Drawing

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, draw

Can you draw a Bitmap to a Canvas by telling it to draw Bitmap's X,Y at Canvas' X1,Y1?  Rather than drawing Bitmap's 0,0 at Canvas X1, Y1?

Answer (score 2):

That's truly possible the `Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)` is here to help. You can specify src region to draw. Look at [Canvas docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) for more.

Also you may use `Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)` to extract that part of original image you want to render. Then just render extracted `Bitmap` as ususal. More info about the method is available on [Google's docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and there's definitely some useful reading in there.  However, you've made me realise my explanation is unclear.  I still want to draw ALL of Bitmap1 next to Bitmap 2...I just want to centre the drawing of Bitmap1 on the Canvas at X1,Y1 AROUND the Bitmap's X,Y.

Don't worry if this makes no sense to you, I know I'm mangling what I'm trying to say! :)